# Why Android Constraint Baseline_toBaselineOf not working Vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/playButton"
        android:layout_width="73dp"
        android:layout_height="62dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nextMusic"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="66dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/previousMusic"
            android:layout_width="73dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/playButton"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm trying to align these three widgets by "app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf", however, as shown on the result below, it does not seem to align properly:

[image]

How could I align them and send them to the screen bottom?

Answer (score 1):

*ImageViews* don't have baselines, so remove all baseline constraints. Remove the `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` constraint on the play button. This will send the play button to the bottom of the screen. (Constraining to the top and the bottom centers the widget.)

Once the play button is at the bottom, you can then adjust the other views. See the documentation for [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout#CenteringPositioning).

Comment: Thanks! After remove all baselines but reserve the app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent", both views will align at the center. And using app:layout_constraintVertical_bias can help me control them to hang in the right place.